# Can I give an app that I purchased in the Software Center to somebody else ? (And related questions.)

Tags: ubuntu-one, software-center

I have purchased a lot of content in the Ubuntu Software Center (apps and magazines) and I also have purchased music in the Ubuntu One Music Store. I have a few related questions about the transmission of this content to another person.

- Do I have the legal right to transmit this content to other people ? To my family ? To my heirs ? To my close friends ? To remote acquaintances ?
- When I do transmit such content, should I delete it from my own devices ? Or can I copy it ?
- Do I have the right to sell it over ?
- If I indeed have the right to transmit content, how should I do it ? For instance, should I transmit my Single Sign On email address and password ?

---

If some of those questions should be asked separately, please tell me in the comments and I will post them as new questions.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the license of each app/magazine/song.  For the programs and magazines you got through Software Center, the "More Info" page for each app or magazine will tell you the license that it is under (under the description and above the review section).

If it is under a proprietary license, you're rights to redistribute are in all likelihood severely limited (or non-existent).  For many of the other licenses you might see there, see: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/ to find out the rights and responsibilities you have if you want to redistribute.